# BigCommerce Stencil Start Error 'useBuiltIns options'

Tags: bigcommerce

I have setup the Stencil CLI and it was working fine, until a few weeks ago, when it started giving me the error:

WARNING: We noticed you're using the `useBuiltIns` option without declaring a core-js version. Currently, we assume version 2.x when no version is passed. Since this default version will likely change in future versions of Babel, we recommend explicitly setting the core-js version you are using via the `corejs` option.

You should also be sure that the version you pass to the `corejs` option matches the version specified in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` section. If it doesn't, you need to run one of the following commands:

npm install --save core-js@2    npm install --save core-js@3
  yarn add core-js@2              yarn add core-js@3

I have updated the node version, reinstalled npm multiple times but with no effect. Also have run the commands mentioned above.

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue? Thanks a lot! Shivam

Answer (score 6):

You only have to add `corejs: 2` or `corejs: 3` to your preset options depending on what version you're using:

In babel.config.js

```
const presets = [['@babel/preset-env', { useBuiltIns: 'usage', corejs: 2 }]];

module.exports = { presets };
```

In .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can read about other allowed values here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env#corejs

I made some notes and a working configuration of babel7 here: https://github.com/hdt94/notes-babel

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This issue report on babel's github repo might helpful:

- [[@babel/preset-env] Provides broken warnings on compile with useBuiltIns #9751](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9751)

Also, several commenters successfully stopped the warnings by making the changes described in this vuejs issue report:

- [Fix babel useBuiltIns core-js warning #1471](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/1471)

Hope that helps,

A